# php multilanguage script and security

Tags: php, security, multilingual

I use this script to enable multilanguage on my website :

```
<?php
// Start a Session, You might start this somewhere else already.
session_start();

// What languages we support
$available_langs = array('en','ro');

if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){
    // check if the language is the one we support
    if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs))
    {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // Set session
    }
}

// Set our default language session ONLY if we've got nothing
if ($_SESSION['lang']=='') {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
$language = $_SESSION['lang'];
setcookie("lang", $language, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), null, null, null, true);

// Include active language
include('languages/lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');
?>
```

My question is: how secure is this, the way it is coded right now and what should I do to improve security ? I administer a VPS using Plesk 12 and have Website Firewall ModSecurity on and I see lots of attempts to upload files in my website's root by using POST method through the browser, taking advantage of the "lang" variable.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks OK. Why are you worried the worst that could happen is they try to "include" a file that does not exist?

Comment: See, one night I got a file called "admin.php" put in a subfolder of my root directory. It's all scramnled and they used it to send spam. Out of 27000+ email spams, just a couple of hundreds "passed" through. Now first, I'm wondering how the heck was it possible in the first place to put the file there, if they don't know the ftp password? They did it through the browser (Mozilla ) and the browser language was set to zh-CN so it's all clear :) ... and second, how come the postfix sent those emails that passed ? Without username and password ?

Comment: What I finally did, I installed the Failed2Ban extension and now I have a whole entreprise of banning the attacks on my VPS, specially through... SSH !!! Hundreds of attempts. Additionally I set headers for apache like x-frame-options, xss, etc ... Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly safe from the looks of it. You are setting a sensible default (en) if not found/not specified, and are pattern matching for en/ro properly.

You may want to consider using a language supporting framework/class though, as it will make your duplication efforts much easier. Try checking out https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n

Comment: Checked it and it looks super nice. It will however require a lot of effort to change what I have so far because I have lots of variables already translated. So what exactly are the benefits of using this vs. what I already have ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: One other quick question. The php-i18n script uses a "langcache" directory with permissions that have to be set to 777. Isn't that unsafe ?

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly safe in case of language. But please check if session has already started otherwise it will throw session_already_started error.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
$availableLanguages = array("en","ro");
$_SESSION['language'] = "en";
$includeFile = "languages/lang.";
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $availableLanguages))
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lang']; 
setcookie("lang", $_SESSION['language'], time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), null, null, null, true);
$includeFile.= $_SESSION['language'].".php";
include($includeFile);
?>
```